# Make a map interactive zone using flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

Need to make a map of a country, with every state. Now, when I press each state then change color. And when all states are press the screen shows a message. How I can do it using actionscript and Flash?

I find an actionscript for count each time anyone click the states. But I want to assing a value of "1" to every ON state and "0" to every OFF. So in the end if the total value (lets say 10) is true, then do something

```
numClicks = 0;
function clicked () {
   numClicks++;
   // add one to numClicks
   if (numClicks>=5) {
      // go to next scene or whatever
   }
}
gotoAndPlay(45);
```

And in actionscript 3.0 the come are something like this:

```
function addClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
   clickCount++;
   _clickTxt.text = " SCORE:"+clickCount.toString();
}
```

Comment: "Questions" that are merely requirements without showing any effort [are subject to removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270903/2596334). They were once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but that's [still being debated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215596/235574). Many people consider it to be rude, so please try to [follow the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- open flash
- draw your map
- convert each separate state/country into a movieclip
- give them a unique name (for example: 'France')
- add the code to your main timeline:

  ```
  addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
  ```

  function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var target:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
    if ( target === null ) return;
    switch ( target.name ) {
      case 'France' :
        // do something for that specific case here...
        break;
      case 'ANOTHER CASE' :
        // do something for that specific case here, etc...
        break;   } }

Voila :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have some issues. I make all the symbols at the map, asign a number to each one. But can´t make it work, what I´m doing wrong?

Here are the file with the code:

[link](http://we.tl/ie6VFDZs6c)

Comment: try that instead:     var clickCount:int = 0;
 
function addClick():void {
      clickCount++;
      _clickTxt.text = " SCORE:"+clickCount.toString();
}


/***************/
addEventListener

(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
 {

 var target:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
 
 if ( target === null ) return;
 
 switch ( target.name )
  { 
   case '01' : addClick() // do something for that specific case here... 
   break;
   case '02' : addClick() // do something for that specific case here, etc... 
   break;
  }
 }

Comment: Thank you very much. I can´t make it work with that code, but I really apreciate your effort. Bye